# Not execution of shell script with nohup

Tags: bash, shell, nohup

I have a problem executing a shell script with the "modifier" nohup.
The script executed without nohup works fine.

The script have all the rights. And the error message is really weird.

```
oracle@serveur6:/home/oracle/xxx/yyy/test>ls -ltr
total 16
-rwxrwxrwx    1 oracle   dba            1620 Jun  7 14:56 lanceur2.sql
-rwxrwxrwx    1 oracle   dba              48 Jun  7 14:56 alt_script.ksh
drwxrwxrwx    2 oracle   dba             256 Jun  7 14:57 log

oracle@serveur6:/home/oracle/xxx/yyy/test> nohup /home/oracle/admin/ESPACE/test/alt_script.ksh &
[1]     25493628
oracle@clay925p6:/home/oracle/admin/ESPACE/test> Sending output to nohup.out
nohup: /home/oracle/admin/ESPACE/test/alt_script.ksh: **No such file or directory**

[1] +  Done(127)               nohup /home/oracle/admin/ESPACE/test/alt_script.ksh &
```

Comment: Is `xxx/yyy` supposed to be `admin/ESPACE`? It simply looks like you are providing a non-existant file as the argument to `nohup`.

Comment: `nohup` is not a modifier in `bash`; it is an external program that runs a given command.

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

1. The path to the script is correct.
2. The script has executable permission set.
3. the first line of the script contains something like `#!/bin/sh`

`nohup` runs a command in the background, thus the script must be executable like any other command.